# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting a `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError` after submitting my form. The error is `unknown attribute: conversation_id` on the line `@question = @conversation.questions.new(params[:question])`

I added `conversation_id` to attributes but it did not make a change. Not sure what else the error could be pointing to.

Questions controller:

```
  def create
    @conversation = Conversation.create
    @question = @conversation.questions.new(params[:question])
      if @question.save
        @message = current_user.messages.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
                               :body => @question.question)
        @question.message = @message
        @question.save
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
      else
        render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
      end
    end
  end
```

Conversation model:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_messageable

  attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :conversation_id

  has_many :questions

end
```

User model:

```
  attr_accessible :role, :notification_id, :sender_id, :receiver_id, :conversation_id, :no_email, :average_response_time, :response_rate, :response_total, :name, :time_zone, :code, :lat, :lon, :city, :age, :age_end, :password_confirmation, :about_me, :feet, :inches, :password, :birthday, :career, :children, :education, :email, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :name, :password_digest, :politics, :religion, :sexuality, :user_drink, :user_smoke, :username, :zip_code
```

Question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :conversation_id
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :sender,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key => 'sender_id'

  belongs_to :recipient,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

  belongs_to :message

  belongs_to :conversation


  end
```

Comment: Did you forget to add `conversation_id` field in `questions` table?

Comment: what's the param hash that's going into the function?

Comment: @KirtiThorat ah that would be correct! Simply over look! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute: conversation_id` on following line

```
@question = @conversation.questions.new(params[:question])
```

because you didn't create `conversation_id` field in `questions` table which is required as you have setup 1-M association between `Conversation` and `Question` model.

To resolve this error you need to add `conversation_id` field in `questions` table.